# How to make the od="log" element default not set to hidden in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have this page in which I slightly modified the jQuery autocomplete to make it somewhat more intuitive and easier to use: http://www.problemio.com/problems/edit_problem.php?problem_id=222

It is an edit page, which means that some categories have been entered already when originally entering the item, but the textarea that contains the matched items in the autocomplete is hidden - and I want it to be displayed as a default. Is that possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery for this, try:

```
// On document ready
$(function(){
     $("#log").show();
});
```

It will show the #log textarea after the document is loaded.

About the dropdown, as far as I can see the HTML, there is no data within .ui-autocomplete